# What conditions does docker swarm use to redirect to a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am using docker swarm with multiple notes and multiple instances of one docker image. As far as I know is there no influence about which container I interact with after a request.
But how does the swarm leader/ manager decides to which container I am talking to?
Is there any pattern or is it just random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is round-robin per connection by the node initially receiving the connection. Under the covers, there are some iptables entries that send requests to [IPVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Virtual_Server). Between the nodes, it's using VXLAN for overlay networking. And within a single node, connections are mapped with various iptables rules, bridge networks, and virtual ethernet interfaces.